# How would I catch an event from an executable?

Tags: vb.net, exe

So, I have an executable I am running in a program. One of the functions the .exe runs is this

`Private Sub FileFound(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)`

How would I access the 'e' argument from my code?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to somehow access the method parameters from a different application?  If so then the answer is that you wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out. Apparently, I can create a 'System.Diagnostics.Process' object and assign it to a variable. Then access the events from that variable.